# How to call the Semantic UI dropdown() function directly on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

`$('#myid').dropdown();` works fine in Semantic UI but `myElement.dropdown()` reports
`TypeError: myElement.dropdown is not a function`.

I cannot use `$` because the element does not have an ID as it gets automatically generated by Semantic UI out of a select element. How can I call `dropdown()` directly on it?

Comment: What is `myElement`? Mind adding some code you're dealing with?

Comment: @Dumisani: my element is the dropdown element (for example the one with id "myid" in the first example). I don't want to add code because it should work in the general case not only in a specific one.